# How to use different storyboards for iPhone and iPad in Xcode6?

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I am trying to work with Xcode 6.1. How can I use different storyboards for iPhone and iPad in Xcode 6.1? I mean, I want to create two different storyboards for iPhone and iPad, and the app will determine which storyboard is to be presented when launching.

I know that I can turn "Use Size Classes"(in the settings of a storyboard file) off to make a storyboard for only iPhone or iPad. But "Main Interface" in the target settings can be only one storyboard. So I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite feature of Xcode 6 so far is the new size classes concept in Interface Builder.
They also enable the condensing of universal apps into one storyboard file.
Combined with the new adaptive view controllers, it's easier then ever to rely on interface builder, rather than fight with it, to simplify the creation of your app layouts. Every view controller in your app gets a trait collection object.

This trait collection object has 2 size classes, a horizontal size class and a vertical size class. And each of these classes has 3 possible values: compact, regular, or any. These values can change based on the device and its orientation.

Your app will layout its interface for each view controller based on the current size classes. Apple uses a grid to let the user choose which configuration to work in, so here's that same grid but with each device+orientation highlighted in its corresponding size class combo.

Kindly refer the [Link](http://www.learnswift.io/blog/2014/6/12/size-classes-with-xcode-6-and-swift)